# How to make this JSON into World Map?

Tags: json, dictionary, d3.js

I downloaded this file: https://gist.github.com/markmarkoh/2969317

And tried it with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
path {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 0.25px;
  fill: grey;
}
</style>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="gistfile1.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([0, 5 ])
    .scale(900)
    .rotate([-180,0]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var g = svg.append("g");

// load and display the World
d3.json("gistfile1.json", function(error, topology) {
    g.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.countries)
          .geometries)
    .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's not working. I am new to d3 world maps so I am kind of lost. I tried a few tutorials but I couldn't get it to work. Could someone help explain where the error is it in my code? And how could I add points to the map?

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to load a json file but supply a js file.

1. rename the gist file from .js to .json
2. remove the `var countries_data =` part.
3. load the `gistfile1.json` file instead of the `json/world-110m2.json` file.

Comment: I did this.. My code now looks like it does above(I edited it with the changes) but I am still getting a blank page.